# Randomizing a circular linked list with adjacency rules

Tags: algorithm, random, linked-list

Let's say you have a big round table of arbitrary size, and you want to seat all your guests at the table *mostly* randomly, but with some rules about adjacency.

Example: Alice, Bob, Charlie, Dan, Eve, Frank, Gerry, and Heidi are coming to dinner. Create a random seating arrangement such that Alice isn't next to Gerry and Charlie isn't next to Frank.

So far, because I'm lazy and it works, I've been doing this by shuffling the list and then just reshuffling if the result violates any of the adjacency restrictions. I've been lucky, though, that my "guest list" is large and my restrictions are few, so failure cases are rare.

I'm guessing the *better* solution involves:

- Using tail recursion so that I only back up as far as necessary to resolve conflicts instead of reshuffling the whole list and hoping for the best.
- Sorting the initial list by each entry's number of exclusions, so that "fussier" items are resolved first, while there are more options remaining in the tail.

While I'm working on it, though, I find myself wondering if there's a way to detect up front whether a certain list's adjacency exclusions are impossible to satisfy. Maybe by building a tree of "legal" options and seeing if its depth is < the length of the list?

Comment: Note that the Hamiltonian cycle problem reduces to this one (the restrictions are the edges that aren't in the graph), so there isn't going to be a way that is guaranteed to be efficient.

Comment: I should emphasize that even determining whether or not a valid seating exists is NP-complete, so sometimes your algorithm will just fail or take exponential time.

Answer (score 4):

It can be remarkably difficult to add constraints to a space being sampled without biasing the distribution. If you do partial backtracking then you privilege the earlier-placed items over the later-placed ones, making the earlier-placed ones' distribution closer to that expected from an (unconstrained) random shuffle while magnifying the effect of the constraints on the later-placed ones. Consider a case where only Alice, Yolanda, and Zelda are allowed to sit next to Beth. If you assign seats alphabetically, backtracking as you hit unresolvable situations, Alice is much less likely than either of the other two to end up next to Beth, since Beth is unlikely to be initially placed next to Alice, and your backtracking will never make you move Beth.

What you call "lazy" is known as [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling), and it is often the preferred approach for this sort of problem, so don't sell it short. For situations where you're going to be rejecting a *lot* of your space there's a couple of variants of rejection sampling which can work well once you get your head around them. I've also had good results using [the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm), which is (IMO) easier to understand and leverage. If you only want one sample, you'd do the burn-in phase and then just take the current state.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent and detailed response. I'm not as worried about bias in my specific case than I might be if it were a higher-stakes application, but I'm glad to know that my existing approach isn't necessarily horrible. As a side question, let's say I decided to stick with rejection sampling as my basis, but with a maximum number of reshuffles before giving up. Is there a reasonable way to calculate a reasonable maximum based on the number of items in the list? Or would I be better off just using the same maximum every time?

Comment: I actually wouldn't expect standard backtracking to perform particularly well here, only to be reliable. If it were me, I'd first try a bunch of rejection sampling passes, and then fall back to something like backtracking if they all failed.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't described any restrictions on your constraints.  As such, the simple answer is "no": there is no method of determining whether a solution exists, short of working through all allowable sequences in search of one that satisfies all constraints.

**If** you can characterize your constraints, then you *can* direct the search dependent on those properties.  **If** the constraints *all* have logical properties amenable to formal proof, then you'd have a system in which you'd have a chance of getting a "yes/no" result with a search on the constraint space, rather than the N! space of the brute-force seating search.

---

**POSSIBLE APPROACH**

We would like to seat the biggest complainers first: start by solving known problems before they cause a seating failure.

1. Initialize a `seat_next` list to empty.
2. Pick a random unseated person named in the constraints; add to `seat_next`.
3. Pop a person from `seat_next`.
4. Find a valid seat for that person; if none, return failure (backtrack).
5. Add everyone else named in that constraint to `seat_next`.
6. If `seat_next` is empty, recur to step 2; otherwise, recur to step 3.

There are still many tuning elements to consider, depending on the interaction and type of constraint.  For instance, you might weight people according to the quantity of constraints in which they appear; you might want to stack or queue the constraints so that you tend to satisfy one constraint before going to the next.

Comment: My constraints are all of the type "A should not be next to [B, C, D]." There are no "A must be next to B" or arcane meta-rules like "A can't sit next to anyone with an e in their name."